# Replace relative path

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, relative-path

I need to strip the directory levels of a relative URL and replace slashes with underscores.
Some of those relative URLs include one or two levels up (./ or ../../). right now I'm using:

```
$('area, a').click(function() { 
      cleanPath = $(this).attr('href').replace(/'..'/g, "").replace(/\//g, "_") );
});
```

But that doesn't work. There are similar questions posted here but nothing that seems to address my specific issue. Obviously, I'm not a RegEx expert.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you want to change them into full URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex, `/'..'/g` looks for all matches of an apostrophe followed immediately by any character followed immediately by any character followed by another apostrophe. This is because `.` matches any character except newlines (unless multiline mode is enabled).

Try either:

```
/\.\./g
```

or

```
/[.]{2}/g
```

By prepending a backslash, your regex treats the `.` as a literal `.` (i.e., a period).

By enclosing `.` in `[.]`, the regex also treats the `.` as a literal `.` (`{2}` is for exactly 2 occurences, back-to-back).